# if its true for $n$ is it true for $n-1$ (mathematical induction)?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, induction

the induction rule , if we suppose that $p(n)$ is true  , is $p(n-1)$ true as well?
if $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
is it true than $1+2+...+n-1=n-1(n-1)/2$ (before proving the statement for $p(n+1)$ )

I hope I made myself clear

Tldr; can we use $p(n-1)$ to prove $p(n+1)$

Comment: Do you know of the distinction between "weak mathematical induction" and "strong mathematical induction"?

Comment: i read about it on wikipedia , english isn't my native language so i didn't understand much , i'm sorry if this seems disrespectful but is the answer yes or no?my head hurts  ( i posted a similiar question not too long ago and people kept downvoting it , ihave no idea why) i had no problem with this site but when it comes to this specific question suddenly everyone just ignores

Comment: If you only use the $n$ case to prove the $n+1$ case, then you're doing weak mathematical induction. If you use any other cases $1$ through $n-1$, then you're using strong mathematical induction. For some proofs you need strong induction, but for some, you can just use weak induction. Both are valid proof techniques.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $p(n)$ implies $p(n-1)$, however to get to your real point: the principle of weak induction is equivalent to the principle of strong induction. Usually what refer to as "mathematical induction" is actually weak induction. In the principle of strong induction, you establish the truth of $p(k)$ for your base case and _assume_ that $p(m)$ is true for _all_ $m$ between $k$ and some $n$. Then we try to prove that $p(n+1)$ is true based on these. A really good proof that uses strong induction is the proof that all integers greater than one is divisible by a prime.

Comment: Sometimes weak induction is sufficient for problems but sometimes it's easier to use strong induction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is yes. If you're going to use the $n$ case and the $n-1$ case, then you need to establish two base cases, though. I.e., show that the claim is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$, and then it follows that it is true for $n=3, 4, \ldots$.

Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: yeah thanks its clear now just saw another article explaining weak and strong inductions